# MockWebServer catch errors

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java

I'm using RxJava, Retrofit and MockWebServer I'm doing unit tests on my services.

My restAdapter have a custom error handler returning a custom throwable depending on the error code :

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setErrorHandler(new RetrofitErrorHandler(context))
```

I tried to use a TestSubscriber and to subscribe like this:

```
    TestSubscriber<X> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    Observable<X> observable = mService.myCall(null, email);

    observable.subscribe(testSubscriber);
```

but the .getOnErrorEvents() returns 0 event.

What should I do ?

Comment: Why are you thinking that there are should be error events?

Comment: Oh, forgot to tell sorry, My mockwebserver has a dispatcher returning a 422 response

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit returns as a successful onNext event any kind of response, even if the status code differs from 2XX.

I propose to map the response and manually throw an error if the response.isSuccess() method returns false.

```
public Observable<UserEntity> loginUser(UserEntity user, String password) {
    return this.restApi.doLogin(user.getEmail(), password)
            .map(new Func1<Response<UserEntity>, UserEntity>() {
                @Override
                public UserEntity call(Response<UserEntity> userEntityResponse) {
                    if (!userEntityResponse.isSuccess()) throw new RuntimeException();
                    return userEntityResponse.body();
                }
            });
}
```